# How to resize a Virtual Box Vm?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have a vm of windows server 2003 that someone created but they made it way to small and I ran already out of space.

How can I re size it?

I have virtual box 4.1 and the file type of the vm is .vmdk

I am running the vm on a windows 7 machine.

**Edit**

I get the following error when I try to resize hard disk.

```
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not impleme
nted yet!



UUID:        e6ab2a89-7db9-4445-a3f0-5d59cc5aee6b
Parent UUID: base
Format:      VMDK
Location:    C:\SomePath\MyVm.vmdk
State:       created
Type:        normal
Usage:       Rezolution - RezRez (UUID: b3cede23-71a7-40a3-a88e-1c49da60da4c)


C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage modifyvdi --resize 42000 e6ab2a89-
7db9-4445-a3f0-5d59cc5aee6b
```

Answer (score 1):

First, shut down the machine and use either `VBoxManage list hdds` or `VBoxManage showvminfo "your vm name" | grep UUID` to find the UUID/filename of the disk:

```
$ VBoxManage list hdds
UUID:        1234aa6e-77e9-4997-b703-f0db02f95678 # <--
Parent UUID: base
Format:      VMDK
Location:    /home/chobo2/VirtualBox VMs/your-vm/your-vm.vdi
State:       created
Type:        normal
Usage:       your-vm (UUID: 4d38b281-bea8-43ba-9e00-aaab9e2e16da)
```

or

```
$ VBoxManage showvminfo "Ubuntu" | grep UUID
UUID:            4d38b281-bea8-43ba-9e00-aaab9e2e16da
Hardware UUID:   4d38b281-bea8-43ba-9e00-aaab9e2e16da
SATA Controller (0, 0): /home/chobo2/VirtualBox VMs/your-vm/your-vm.vdi
    (UUID: 1234aa6e-77e9-4997-b703-f0db02f95678)  # <--
```

Then, simply use [`VBoxManage modifyvdi --resize`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi), where `42000` is the desired new size in MB:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvdi --resize 42000 1234aa6e-77e9-4997-b703-f0db02f95678
```

Comment: I am running it on a windows 7 machine will this work?

Comment: Sure, virtually all of the VirtualBox tools are available on all hosts. If you don't have cygwin, `grep` won't work. You can either search manually or [use `FindStr`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/87394/35070).

Comment: Hey, I been quite busy and did not want to try this till I was finished using the vm. I tried the steps but I get this error:Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not impleme
nted yet!

Comment: It looks like your disk is in vmdk format. Either use VMWare to resize the disk, or [convert it to vdi](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi) with `VBoxManage clonehd C:\SomePath\MyVm.vmdk --format vdi C:\SomePath\MyVm.vdi` and *then* resize it.

Comment: Which VmWare product do I need? Is it free?

Comment: According to [their documentation](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004047) ([mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20110208124450/http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004047)), it should work with Fusion, Player, Workstation, ACE Manager, Server, and GSX. None of these are [free software](http://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software), but Player and Server don't cost anything, and you can evaluate Workstation for 30 days.

Comment: Ok So I converted it to vdi but I am not sure how to resize it now as when I try to use VBoxManage but it does not find this new vdi vm. How can I add it to virtual box so it know about it. That way I can then resize it?

Comment: @chobo2 You can add it in the GUI or [attach it with `VBoxManage`](http://serverfault.com/questions/171665/how-to-attach-a-virtual-hard-disk-using-vboxmanage). In any case, simply passing the the filename to `VBoxManage modifyvdi` should work, like this: `VBoxManage modifyvdi --resize 42000 C:\SomePath\MyVm.vdi`.

Comment: Ok I did that and it does the operation almost instantly but the size of vdi still looks the same.

Comment: That's correct; VirtualBox doesn't allocate the disk space until it's really needed. Go boot into the machine, and resize the partitions.

Comment: Ok. Well I converted to .vdi and then re-sized but the vm now seems messed. I have a c# program(that I made) and I tried to launch the .exe in the release folder and it won't load up(I see the .exe in processes but now gui shows up). I went to my original vm with the same code set and it works fine. It also seems to have problems connecting to my corporate network. I guess I will try to re-size with vmware and see if that works.